# how to get headers from urllib2.read() written in django's NamedTemporaryFile?

Tags: python, django, urllib2

Im trying to use django's NamedTemporaryFile for storing instace from urllib. Here are some codes.

```
import urllib2
import types

from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile    
img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile()
img_temp = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/images/python-logo.gif').read()
img_temp.write(img_temp)
```

How can I get the header from img_temp? The img_temp variable is a string. And what is the difference between this two codes? Why do they return different types?

```
a = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/images/python-logo.gif')
a.read()
b = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/images/python-logo.gif').read()

print 'a %s'% type(a)
print 'b %s'% type(b)
```

Results:

```
a <type 'instance'>
b <type 'str'>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To get header information you can use `.info`

```
a = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/images/python-logo.gif')
print a.info()
```

As stated in [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> info() — return the meta-information of the page, such as headers, in
>   the form of an mimetools.Message instance (see Quick Reference to HTTP
>   Headers)

`urllib2.urlopen` returns the file like object that is why `type(a)` is `instance`, but when you are doing `a = a.read()` you are actually fetching the content of url and you are overwriting on the same variable that is why now `type(a)` is `str`.